# Set width of HTML td the same as image in td has

Tags: java, html, jsoup

This question isn't probably right one to be placed here, but maybe you could save me some hours of work by a little advice.

Could it be done by jsoup? Or should I iterate through the whole html document: get starting `td` tag then the ending one and then get width of image in between the tags. Do it like that for all `td's`?

Sounds a little complex.

Comment: i think by default the size of `td` is same as its inner child.

Comment: The issue is that sometimes you need to remove the image and put text there, then you must add td height and width to the TD.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following CSS:

```
td img {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your image dimension always changes, do it with javascript:

Html:

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td id="imageHeight">
      <img src="">
   </td>
   <td id="textHeight">
       text
   </td>
</tr>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
var image = document.getElementById("imageHeight").offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("textHeight").offsetHeight = image;
</script>
```

The `offsetHeight` property is similar to the `clientHeight` property, but it returns the height including the padding, scrollBar and the border.